# Calling native function from the Android API level 28 Application

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have created a pre-built Native library libNative.so, that has a JNI function to be called from the Android application.
libNative.so is located in the device at /system/x86_64.
Now, I want to call the JNI function implemented in my pre-built Native library from Android application. I am following below Procedure.

1> Load the Native lib in MainActivity:

```
static    {    System.loadLibrary("Native");    }
```

2> Declared the native method as:

```
 public native int Init();
```

3> Function definition in the shared lib is:

```
JNIEXPORT jint Java_App_PACKAGE_NAME_MainActivity_Init(JNIEnv* env, jobject callingObject){  
return 0;  
}
```

4>I'm calling the native function in onCreate:

```
int i = Init();
```

Now If I build and run the application. I get the error as:

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int App_PACKAGE_NAME_MainActivity.Init() (tried Java_App_PACKAGE_NAME_MainActivity_Init and Java_App_PACKAGE_NAME_MainActivity_Init__)
```

Please help me to resolve the above error.
Why is it that I get linker error even though loading of the library is success.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake I was doing.The definition of JNI function in the native library was wrong. I changed as below and everything started working!.
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_App_PACKAGE_NAME_MainActivity_Init(JNIEnv* env, jobject callingObject){
}